# Retrieving the name of the Submit Button with Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a front end page which has a a set of submit buttons and the snippet is:

```
<div class="table-outer">
<div class="table-inner">
<table>
<form action="addtocart" method="post" >    
<tr><td>IIT Jee Prep Combo pack</td><td><input type="submit" name="IIT Jee Prep Combo pack " value="Add to Cart"></td></tr>
</form>
<form action="addtocart" method="post">    
<tr><td>GRE Prep Combo Pack</td><td><input type="submit" name="GRE Prep Combo Pack" value="Add to Cart"></td></tr>
</form>
<form action="addtocart" method="post">    
<tr><td>GATE Prep Combo Pack </td><td><input type="submit" name="GATE Prep Combo Pack" value="Add to Cart" ></td></tr>
</form>
<form action="addtocart" method="post">    
<tr><td>CAT Prep Combo Pack</td><td><input type="submit" name"CAT Prep Combo Pack" value="Add to Cart"></td></tr>
</form>
<form action="addtocart" method="post">
<tr><td>Civil Services Prep Combo Pack</td><td><input type="submit" name="Civil Services Prep Combo Pack" value="Add to Cart"></td></tr>
</form>    
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

I have a Flask server handling all the requests. Now, I want to store the name of the
 book in a file when the user clicks. The name of the book is stored in the name attribute of the form tag. How can I perform this. If it were a text box, I did it with request.form['name']. How can the same be performed in case of a submit button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser sends only the submit button used over to the server; you can test for that name in the `request.form` object:

```
if "Civil Services Prep Combo Pack" in request.form:
    # ...
```

or you could look for the form keys; there should be just one key in the form, which will be the `name` attribute of the submit button used:

```
book = form.keys()[0]
```

In other words, the `name` attribute of a submit button is the key of the submitted field; the associated value is always going to be `'Add to Cart'` for your forms.

It'll be *much* easier to test for what form was used if you added a hidden field to each form:

```
<form action="addtocart" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="book" value="Civil Services Prep Combo Pack" />
<tr><td>Civil Services Prep Combo Pack</td><td><input type="submit" name="add" value="Add to Cart"></td></tr>
</form>
```

and use `request.form['book']` to determine what form was used.

Comment: Tried like this:
   @app.route('/addtocart', methods=['GET','POST'])
    def addtocart():
       if request.method=='POST':
          book_ordered=request.form['book']
          if book_ordered=="Five Point Someone":
              return render_template('Novellist.html')

This is not working. The server says it a bad request. Help

Comment: book_ordered=request.form['book'] is not responding.

Comment: And what is the exception you get? `KeyError` perhaps? Did you check if your browser actually has a hidden input field to submit? You could do `return str(request.form)` in a view to test what exactly was submitted in your POST to help debug.

Comment: As far I know request.form[book] has to retrieve the value part of the form that is submitted. However, The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand is popping out.

Comment: When I use return str(request.form] , this gets returned :

     ImmutableMultiDict([('Five Point Someone', u'Add to Cart')])

Comment: @user3531196: So you didn't actually add the `<input type="hidden">` elements to your  form. `request.form.keys()[0]` would work, however, that'd be `'Five Point Someone'` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than overloading the submit button, I'd suggest putting the name of the book as a hidden tag. That way it'll be sent to the server, so you can do something like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="book_name" value="Name of Book here" />
```

and then access request.form['book_name'].

The other way to do this is via Javascript and overriding the submit method to know what submit button was clicked on.

Check out [Flask-WTF](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and [WTForms](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), by the way. You can create your forms programmatically, and I think it's a lot neater than coding forms by hand.

Comment: Oops, I missed Martijn suggested a hidden tag, too.